# Grails 3 Spring security config not working when configured inside application.yaml file

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-spring-security

In grails 3 spring security rest...config inside application.yaml is not being picked up but when i am trying with application.groovy everything works fine.Please help i am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you receive an error, can you not login?
Have you migrated from an earlier version of grails and have copied the formatting over from groovy to yml?
I have my config in yml along the lines of the following with 4 spaces (rather than tabs) for the nesting.

```
grails:
    plugin:
        springsecurity:
            active: true
            useSecurityEventListener: false
```

Also I notice you've specified application.yaml as the file name, not sure if it makes any difference but I don't have the 'a' in my file i.e. application.yml